# how to add interdependent libraries in a makefile

Tags: c, linux, makefile

I need to make a makefile for my project and I have two interdependent libraries which are libpcsc.so and libccid.so .

could someone tell me what my mistake is? Thanks for your answers in advance.

and please let me know when you need more information.

my makefile is like:

by the way, one of lib directory is /home/hasanbucak/Desktop/pcsc-lite-1.8.23/src/.libs/  and  other one's is usr/lib/pcsc/drivers/ifd-ccid.bundle/Contents/Linux/

```
 CC = gcc

 LIB_DIRS = -L/home/hasanbucak/Desktop/pcsc-lite-1.8.23/src/.libs/ 
 -L../../usr/lib/pcsc/drivers/ifd-ccid.bundle/Contents/Linux/ 

 INCLUDE_DIR = /home/hasanbucak/Desktop/ccid-1.4.28/src/ #ccid_usb.h

 CFLAGS = -g -Wall

obj-y:= smcard

default: all


all: smcard

smcard: 
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) $(LIB_DIRS)  -I$(INCLUDE_DIR) -c -o $(obj-y).o $(obj-y).c
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -lccid -lpcsclite  $(LIB_DIRS) -I$(INCLUDE_DIR) -o $(obj-y) $(obj-y).c  




clean:
    rm $(obj-y).o $(obj-y)
```

and when I write make in terminal , it says:

```
hasanbucak@ubuntu:~/Desktop/hasan$ make
gcc -g -Wall -L/home/hasanbucak/Desktop/pcsc-lite-1.8.23/src/.libs/ -L../../usr/lib/pcsc/drivers/ifd-ccid.bundle/Contents/Linux/   -I/home/hasanbucak/Desktop/ccid-1.4.28/src/ -c -o smcard.o smcard.c
gcc -g -Wall -lccid -lpcsclite  -L/home/hasanbucak/Desktop/pcsc-lite-1.8.23/src/.libs/ -L../../usr/lib/pcsc/drivers/ifd-ccid.bundle/Contents/Linux/  -I/home/hasanbucak/Desktop/ccid-1.4.28/src/ -o smcard smcard.c  
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lccid
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
Makefile:20: recipe for target 'smcard' failed
make: *** [smcard] Error 1
```

Comment: *"could someone tell me what my mistake is?"* What mistake? You haven't mentioned what the problem is. Please [edit] your question and add necessary information.

Comment: You wrote that ccid is in usr/lib/pcsc/drivers/ifd-ccid.bundle/Contents/Linux/  yet you refer to it by ../../usr/lib/pcsc/drivers/ifd-ccid.bundle/Contents that is a different directory

Comment: cannot find lccid, find this `ccid` library in your system and make sure you're giving the correct path while linking.

Comment: If they are interdependent, why not combine them into one?

Comment: thank you so much guys .  @beta actually I am in a training and my tutor wanted me to make it in this way and I could not make it so far but now I understood the problem thanks to you all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make already told you what was wrong with the Makefile:

```
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lccid
```

You should specify the path to ccid properly:

```
LIB_DIRS = -L/home/hasanbucak/Desktop/pcsc-lite-1.8.23/src/.libs/ 
  -L/usr/lib/pcsc/drivers/ifd-ccid.bundle/Contents/Linux/
```

Note that `/usr` and `../../usr` are not at all the same directory.

The first one is absolute (i.e. relative to your root directory), while the second is relative, it expands to `~/Desktop/hasan/../../usr`, which is equivalent to `/home/hasanbucak/usr`.